# In my iOS app, I have a script in the build phases that auto-strips unneeded archs from frameworks. In Xcode 12, it has stopped working. Any clues?

Tags: ios, xcode12

I have a mixed Swift / Objective-C Xcode project. I am trying to transition it to Xcode 12, and I am encountering an issue. Since a few years I use the very good script described [here](http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/) to strip unneeded architectures from frameworks which is a requirement when uploading the application for the store. Under Xcode 12 (Release build 12A7209) the script fails because, as I have read in the log, some frameworks executables are already, for some reason, in their single-targeted architecture form, that is only arm64 for the device and only x86_64 for the simulator. In a few words, it appears like if the stripping feature had been added in Xcode itself, but unfortunately it does not work for all frameworks. For quick reference, the following is the script:

```
# Type a script or drag a script file from your workspace to insert its path.
# See http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/
# For more information

APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

# This script loops through the frameworks embedded in the application and
# removes unused architectures.
find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

for ARCH in $ARCHS
do
echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
done

echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

done
```

Please let me know if you need further information. Many thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**

I succeeded in making it work making a few changes. Basically, if the executable is not a far archive, I skip the current iteration. The new script follows:

```
# Type a script or drag a script file from your workspace to insert its path.
# See http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/
# For more information

APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

# This script loops through the frameworks embedded in the application and
# removes unused architectures.
find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

for ARCH in $ARCHS
do
echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH" 2>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Success extracting $ARCH architecture from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
else
    echo "Failed extracting $ARCH architecture from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    continue
fi

done

if [ "${#ARCHS[@]}" -eq "1" ]; then
    echo "There is only one architecture. Skipping"
    rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
    continue
fi

echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"

lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}" 2>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Success Merging"
else
    echo "Failure Merging"
    continue
fi

rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

done
```

I will leave the question open, since my new script works, but I am not certain that it can work in all situations. Thanks again

Comment: Xcode does stripping of universal fat frameworks for a long time already. It’s done automatically if you embed framework through Xcode target linked libraries and frameworks section.

Comment: Please put your solution as an answer, not as an edit to the question.